# how to open playstore app with update page programmatically from my app

Tags: android, google-play

I am comparing version of my app on google play store and version of app in play store. So whenever new version of app get uploaded it shows dialog to user to update the app, but when i click on "Update Button" in dialog, it opens play store with "Open" and "Uninstall" button instead of "Update" and "Uninstall" button.

So please tell me how to open play store app with "Update" and "Uninstall" button when new version is uploaded on play store.

here's my code to open play store.

```
AlertDialog.Builder  dialogUpdate= new AlertDialog.Builder(Main_list_Activity.this,AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL).setTitle("New Version Available")
                .setIcon(getResources()

                .getDrawable(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_download))
                .setMessage("New version of app is available. Update your app")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNeutralButton("UPDATE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        try {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id="+getPackageName())));
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            // TODO: handle exception

                            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName())));

                        }




                    }
                });

    AlertDialog updatedialog = dialogUpdate.create();

        updatedialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Google does not provide any api to get the lattest version of application code.
Google does not provide any API for that.

Nevertheless , you can make an http request on the web version of the playstore (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.namespace)

To make the request you can use DefaultHttpClient

Once you get the page content you should parse it (jsoup is a good solution) and search for :

```
<div class="content" itemprop="softwareVersion"> 2.2.0  </div>
```

Once you find this part of the page , you can extract the version number and compare it with the one available in your app :

```
try
{
    String version = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    if( ! version.equals(versionFromHTML))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "New version available on play store", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

}
catch (NameNotFoundException e)
{
    //No version do something
}
```

For the HTML parsing part , have a look here

Keep in mind that everybody won't see the new version in the same time. It could take time to be propagated (probably because of cache).

Comment: i used same functionality and i use to open a dialog when new version get triggered but as i click on update button in dialog  it opens play store and i don't get update button there play store that's m prob so can u please tell me hoe to get update button in play store.??]

Comment: If already update available then update button visible if not then update button not available

Comment: i haven't update my app yet even i have check version of my app and version off app on play store both are different but still not getting update button.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates which might help you for what you are looking for. If its matches with your need / requirement kindly up vote this thread.